# expand array of struct using realloc C

Tags: c

I'm trying to expand the size of my array by 1 every time when I Enqueue
a new student , and it did work but the problem is it takes a garbage values for the name and id , can you please help me why is this happening ,
thanks .

```
 void Enqueue(Student *arr ,  int index){


    Student *s = NULL ; 
    int size = index + 1 ; 
    Student *temp = (Student*)realloc(s, size*(sizeof(Student)) );

    if (temp == NULL){
    printf("Can not allocate memory !!! \n") ;
    return ;
    }
    else
    arr = temp ;  


    char Name[10] ; int Id ;

    printf("please enter student name : \n");
    scanf("%s" , Name);
    arr[size].name = Name ;

    printf("please enter student ID : \n");
    scanf("%d" , &Id);
    arr[size].id = Id ;


    return ;

}
```

this is the run :

```
Student(5) Name :H�� H9�u�H�[]A\A]A^A_Ðf. � 
Student(5) ID : 1
```

Comment: Can we please have Student?

Comment: Regarding `arr[size].name = Name;` - If this compiles, then `Student::Name` can only be one of two things: `void*` or `char*` (the latter far more likely). That means you're retaining a pointer to an automatic local variable `Name` in this function, which will produce *undefined behavior* the moment it is dereferenced outside this function. You need a real buffer (dynamic or fixed in the `Student` structure) and `strcpy` (or scan directly into the target). And no, it's not the only bug.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc(s, size*(sizeof(Student)) );` must be `realloc(arr, size*(sizeof(Student)) );` (`s` is `NULL`!).

Then, you never return the newly allocated array to the caller:

`arr = temp` does *not* change the passed in pointer. You'd need a pointer to a pointer to return the new value, like

```
void Enqueue(Student **arr ,  int index){
...
  *arr = temp;
...
}
```

or just return the new array:

```
Student* Enqueue(Student *arr, int index) {
...
return temp;
}
```

And then there are the other memory management bugs, as mentioned by @WhozCraig.